# How to dinamically update the child div width after insert other elements in the parent div

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, width

I have a main div (with fixed height and scroll-x and scroll-y):

```
<div style="position:relative;border:solid 2px #000;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:scroll; height:200px; width:100%;" id="pippo">
</div>
```

and a bunch of child div created dynamically in js and inserted in the parent div with absolute position:

```
<div style='z-index:3;position:absolute; top: 50px; left: "+pos+"px;border:solid 1px;'>m</div>
```

This divs can be created everywhere, also beyond the parent div height and width (I don't care because I get the scrollbars).

My problem is:
there are other child divs (created in js) that represent a background like a chart. The divs have a border and a width of 100%. An example of one of them:

```
<div style='z-index:2;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc; color:#ccc;position:absolute;width:100%;bottom:"+yyy+"px;'>0</div>
```

When javascript create dynamically the divs, the background don't update his width to the new one (if the divs go beyond the parent measures).

So, if you scroll on the right, you don't see the background.
How can I do to give the right width (100%) to the background when the parent width is dynamically changed?

http://jsfiddle.net/4x2KP/157/

Thanks everybody!

Comment: I would recommend that you pull those inline styles out into CSS where you can. It will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: @BDawg yes I know, I wrote the question on fly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've do an work around to it, if you can add specific class to the axis divs.

You can listen to the scroll event on the `#pippo` and adjust the offset of the axis, as its fixed horizontally inside the `#pippo`. But you may have to separate the digit part and axis-line part to make the digit part movable by the scrollbar.

```js
var t = 250;
var $axis;
var offsets;
$(document).ready(function(){
    crea_bg();
 setTimeout(function(){ pippo(); }, t);
});
var pos = 0;
function pippo(){
    pos = pos + 30;
    $("#pippo").append("<div style='z-index:3;position:absolute; top: 50px; left: "+pos+"px;border:solid 1px;'>m</div>");
    setTimeout(function(){ pippo(); }, t);
}

function crea_bg(){
    var yyy = 0;
    $("#pippo").append("<div class='axis' style='z-index:2;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc; color:#ccc;position:absolute;width:100%;bottom:"+yyy+"px;'>0</div>");
 for (i = 25; i <= 300; i=i+25) {
  $("#pippo").append("<div class='axis' style='z-index:2;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc; color:#ccc;position:absolute;width:100%;bottom:"+(yyy+(-i))+"px;'>"+(-i)+"</div>");
  $("#pippo").append("<div class='axis' style='z-index:2;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc; color:#ccc;position:absolute;width:100%;bottom:"+(yyy+(i))+"px;'>"+i+"</div>");
 }
  $axis = $('.axis').css('left', 0);
}

$('#pippo').scroll(function() {
    //var currentLeft = parseFloat($axis.css('left'));
   //console.log($axis.css('left'), currentLeft, $axis.position().left);
    //$axis.css('left', currentLeft - $axis.position().left);
  $axis.css('left',  '-=' + $axis.position().left);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;border:solid 2px #000;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:scroll; height:200px; width:100%;" id="pippo">
</div>
```

Comment: Check the difference between firefox and chrome. In chrome is perfect. Firefox has a strange behaviour.... @fuyushimoya

Comment: Got it, I'll see how to fix it.

Comment: @StefanoNinoMancini  Cost lots of times..., the `.offset` in ff seem not just apply left value, but has some other computaions, tried many way, and finally get a method that looks acceptable on both browser, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for, but this code creates those background lines at the same time that the letters are written.

You can adjust it easily changing the "width" var.

```js
var t = 250;
$(document).ready(function(){
 crea_bg();
    setTimeout(function(){ pippo(); }, t);
});
var pos = 0;
function pippo(){
    pos = pos + 30;
    crea_bg();
    $("#pippo").append("<div style='z-index:3;position:absolute; top: 50px;"
  +" left: "+pos+"px;border:solid 1px;'>m</div>");
 setTimeout(function(){ pippo(); }, t);
}

function crea_bg(){
 var yyy = 0;
    
 var width = pos + 30;
    
 $("#pippo").append("<div style='z-index:2;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;" 
  +"color:#ccc;position:absolute;width:"+width+"px;bottom:"+yyy+"px;'>0</div>");
    
 for (i = 25; i <= 300; i=i+25) {
  $("#pippo").append("<div style='z-index:2;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;"
         +" color:#ccc;position:absolute;width:"+width+"px;bottom:"+(yyy+(-i))+"px;'>"+(-i)+"</div>");
  $("#pippo").append("<div style='z-index:2;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;"
         + "color:#ccc;position:absolute;width:"+width+"px;bottom:"+(yyy+(i))+"px;'>"+i+"</div>");
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;border:solid 2px #000;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:scroll; height:200px; width:100%;" id="pippo">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Avoiding the typical document flow**

If you must avoid the typical document flow, you'll need to insert another container between `<div id="pippo">` and its child elements, then manually update the new container's width/height as needed.

**Staying within the typical document flow**

If you don't need to work around the normal document flow and are just searching for any possible way to make a parent expand, use a combination of `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
        $('#pippo').append('<div class="childDiv">m</div>')
    }, 250);
});
```

```css
#pippo {
    border: solid 2px #000;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.childDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pippo"></div>
```